# Ubuntu 20:04 Can't detect display and screen does not fill the display

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, display

Just installed 20:04, and 18:04 have not this problem.

The main problem is that the screen don't fill up the display. In the settings --> displays, it says it is a 'Unknown display. The display are a common HP S2231a.

I have a Nvidia gfx Geforce GT 520.

I tried install Nvidias X11-server config, but Ubuntu says there is missing dependencies but it get installed anyway, but does not work at all. Just white content.

In `Software & Updates`--> **Additional drivers** have 4 rows,

[image]

Number 4 is choosen, and the other 3 row are greyed out, and not possible to select them

I have no idea what manual installed drivers are, and I have not doing anything manual.

What can I do?

joni@HP2:~$ sudo dpkg -l *nvidia*

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                       Version                  Archite>
+++-==========================================-========================-=======>
un  libgldispatch0-nvidia                      <none>                   <none> >
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-42-generic  5.4.0-42.46              amd64  >
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-48-generic  5.4.0-48.52              amd64  >
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic-hwe-20.04 5.4.0-48.52              amd64  >
un  nvidia-304                                 <none>                   <none> >
un  nvidia-340                                 <none>                   <none> >
un  nvidia-384                                 <none>                   <none> >
un  nvidia-common                              <none>                   <none> >
un  nvidia-dkms-390                            <none>                   <none> >
un  nvidia-kernel-common                       <none>                   <none> >
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-390                   390.138-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64  >
un  nvidia-prime                               <none>                   <none> >
rc  nvidia-settings                            440.82-0ubuntu0.20.04.1  amd64  >
un  nvidia-settings-binary                     <none>                   <none> >
lines 1-19/19 (END)
```

Edit.
[image: After help from @heynnema I purge the nividia-driver and ubuntu use Noveau-drivers]

I tried just now to add Nvidias propretarian drivers but get this error message: [image]

Comment: "Unknown Display" usually means a bad cable. Are you using VGA or HDMI, or something else? You "manually installed" the Nvidia **server** driver, which would be incorrect for a Ubuntu desktop installation. Choose the Nouveau driver, uninstall the Nvidia stuff, and come back and choose "Nvidia proprietory" drivers. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: DVI-cable. I can still not select and change driver, even after i have removed Nvidia x-server. /Cheers

Comment: Download the correct Nvidia driver at https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/results/160182/. Report back. Remember to start comments to me with @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema . I downloaded the driver an run as root, but the installee compain rhe X-server or other module was running. Does not an X-server always run, if you have a screen?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `dpkg -l *nvidia*`

Comment: @heynnema  here is the output :

Comment: Either edit your question and add the output there with a paste, or use paste.ubuntu.com.

Comment: It'ds to complicated. can't tag with code or something :[

Comment: I fixed it for you. What you do is paste the text, select the text, click on the {} icon to format it to be human-readable. Choose the nouveau driver in `Software & Updates`. Then, in `terminal` do `sudo apt-get purge *nvidia*`, then try to install the newer driver that you downloaded.

Comment: @heynnema I can't select anything in Software & updates --> Aditional drivers. Manual installed are marked, and the rest of the options are grayed out. In Synaptic.  xserver-xorg-video-noueau 1:1.0.16-1 are marked as installed. Should I go for sudo apt-get purge *nvidia* directly ?

Comment: Yes, go ahead...

Comment: @heynnema It work fine with the nouveau driver. :) So I think I stay here for now. But how is it if you installl drivers and applications manually, do they get updated? Are there no alternative to add another repository/PPA or something instead?

Comment: Yes. What does `Software & Updates` show now in the Additional Drivers tab? Screenshot it for me.

Comment: I have edit the originasal post... It's complicated... :(  Can't see how It be before I edit. Thougt I write a header, but don't se it now. And I have to go to bed now. but how it look now are ther, I think.

Comment: You did great. You can always enable the preview mode so that you can see the outcome of your edits. Go ahead and check the first Nvidia driver, version 390, which is the same as what you downloaded earlier. If it all goes as planned, doing it this way will keep it updated for you, and you'll get the accelerated graphics that you deserve :-). Report back after you wake up.

Comment: @heynnema . It's a toke some time for me to try activate Nvidias drivers, and It did not work :( I edit the original post whit the error message as screen shot. /Cheers

Comment: It's been a while since we last talked... so I need to regroup where we are... had you purged the previous Nvidia software with `sudo apt-get purge *nvidia*` and reverted to the nouveau driver?

Comment: Yes I did. purged Nvidia drivers. Head from a pal that, Nvidia had a security problem, so Nvida releas an update, that Ubuntu/Debian not really implemented. Changes within -390 version. but I dont know.

Comment: @ heynnema . nouveau drivers work, so I think a new install i better than try to find other solutions. Something in the install can being fu*t up. Finding out is more work, than make a new install. But I really love the help you give me. I hate fu*king with computers, was the main cause I left windows ;)

Comment: I was just about to recommend that very action. Go for it!

Comment: :). Left windos in 2004 :)

Comment: Did we ever check to see that your BIOS was up to date?

Comment: Cheers and thank for your help :) In a way... better with open source ;)

Comment: You're very welcome! Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the exact make/model # of your computer.

Comment: Computer say : 6.13

Comment: sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
[sudo] password for joni: 
6.13

Comment: How exactly? Out-print of lshw?

Comment: The easiest way is to look on the computer itself. The brand name, and the series name, are usually visible, and the actual model # can usually be found on a label on the bottom (of the laptop). Otherwise, type `sudo dmidecode -t 1`. With that info, I can go look for the current BIOS version for you. Thanks!