# How to let Ubuntu 20.04.1 recognize an unknown display to adjust its resolution?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, multiple-monitors, display, gpu-driver

I recently updated from Ubuntu 18.04.4 to 20.04.1 on a *Lenovo T400 2765*. When I connected an external *Fujitsu Siemens P19-1A* monitor via VGA it is shown as **"Unknown Display"** in *Settings* > *Displays*. This was **not** the case in Ubuntu 18.04.4.

[image: Screenshot of Settings > Displays]

Also, the native resolution (1280x1024) is **not** available.

Here is what `xrandr` tells about the monitors:

```bsh
$ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 2
 0: +XWAYLAND0 1440/300x900/190+0+768  XWAYLAND0
 1: +XWAYLAND1 1024/271x768/203+0+0  XWAYLAND1
```

...

```bsh
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1440 x 1668, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected 1440x900+0+768 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 300mm x 190mm
   1440x900      60.03*+
XWAYLAND1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      59.92*+
```

There is no additional drivers installed:

[image: Screenshot of Software & Updates > Additional Drivers]

How can I make Ubuntu recognize the monitor? Is there a driver in Ubuntu 18.04.4 which I have to manually install?

I found this very good [article on how to add a custom resolution](https://www.tecmint.com/set-display-screen-resolution-in-ubuntu/) but I would prefer to let Ubuntu recognize the actual monitor (brand/model) as before.

## Related

- [How to make Ubuntu recognize an unknown external display (so I can adjust its resolution)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206275/how-to-make-ubuntu-recognize-an-unknown-external-display-so-i-can-adjust-its-re)
- [Ubuntu 20:04 Can't detect display and screen does not fill the display](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277277/ubuntu-2004-cant-detect-display-and-screen-does-not-fill-the-display)
- [Second monitor suddenly can't be detected (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277720/second-monitor-suddenly-cant-be-detected-ubuntu-20-04-1-lts)

Comment: Lenovo P1 has the same issues

Comment: First make sure your cable works properly 
My problem solved by changing the VGA cable!

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Locate `monitors.xml`, usually in `/home/username/.config/monitors.xml`.
2. Then find the name of unknown display inside `<connector>DP-1</connector>`.
3. Open GRUB using `nano`:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   ```

   or, if you prefer a GUI application such as gedit:

   ```
   gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```
4. Change the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=` to include the name of the unknown display you found in step 2 as follows:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="video=DP-1:d"
   ```
5. Save the changes in `nano` by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> and close the editor by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> (if you used a GUI editor just save as usually and close the editor).
6. Update GRUB:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

Comment: I had a look into `~/.config/monitors.xml`. There is no entry named `DP-1`. How do I recognize the right one?

Comment: The step 4 isn't clear for me. Where is the name supposed to be added? I could solve my issue by using the command `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="video=DP-1:d"` without any name.